# How do you reference the person who said the quote to show on your document?

Tags: html, css, xcode, tags, footer

I added a quote to my document, like so (please see bottom)
The Fred Beecher, Director of UX, is not showing up on my document right underneath the quote. I do have a fixed footer that's positioned at the bottom of the webpage that holds the social media icons. When I do inspect, it looks like the text is placed in the footer with the icons at the bottom. Is it possible to get the Fred Beecher... right underneath the quote?

```html
<article class="quote">
  <blockquote
    cite="https://careerfoundry.com/en/blog/ux-design/15-inspirational-ux-design-quotes-that-every-designer-should-read/"
  >
    <p>
      How do I explain what I do at a party? The short version is that I say I
      humanize technology.
    </p>
    <footer>—Fred Beecher, Director of UX</footer>
  </blockquote>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

**With Bootstrap** this is actually possible. You will get your desired output in below snippet.

**Please note: ** I have included some Bootstrap 4 scripts for this task to work.

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<blockquote class="blockquote">
  <p>How do I explain what I do at a party? The short version is that I say I humanize technology.</p>
  <footer class="blockquote-footer">Fred Beecher, Director of UX</footer>
</blockquote>
```

**UPDATE:** You can also achieve the same by just **removing all the Bootstrap** 4 CDN link paths. Use only CSS to enhance your quotes. Below is the code for CSS followed by HTML markup.

```css
.quote{
font-weight: 600;
font-size: 20px;
font-family: 'Segoe UI Light';
}

.footer
{

font-size: 20px;
font-family: 'Segoe UI Light';
}
```

```html
<blockquote>
  <p class="quote">How do I explain what I do at a party? The short version is that I say I humanize technology.</p>
  <p class="footer">- Fred Beecher, Director of UX</p>
</blockquote>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @seekay, in that case please see my update. I have used pure CSS to enhance the look of your quote.